# How to display images from Photos (original photo gallery in ios)

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, swiftui, xcode-storyboard

I have created an application that displays all images from Photos (not choosing image from photos). For example, Google Photos that can accessing all images from Photos and it can display again on its application. Does anyone know to re-display all images from Photos on our application using swift?

Comment: Hi there, please, post your code so we can review and help you

Comment: [`UIImagePickerController` in `SwiftUI` via `UIViewControllerRepresentable`](https://medium.com/better-programming/implement-imagepicker-using-swiftui-7f2a28caaf9c)

Answer (score 9):

Please try possible approach. Tested in xCode: 11.2.1

**NOTE:** add `Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description` in **`info.plist`** fro permission fro access photo from gallery

```
import SwiftUI
import Photos

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var photos = PhotosModel()
    var body: some View {
        List(photos.allPhotos, id: \.self) { photo in
            Image(uiImage: photo)
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200, alignment: .center)
                .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
        }
        .alert(isPresented: .constant(self.photos.errorString != "") ) {
            Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(self.photos.errorString ), dismissButton: Alert.Button.default(Text("OK")))
        }
    }
}

class PhotosModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var allPhotos = [UIImage]()
    @Published var errorString : String = ""

    init() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            switch status {
            case .authorized:
                self.errorString = ""
                self.getAllPhotos()
            case .denied, .restricted:
                self.errorString = "Photo access permission denied"
            case .notDetermined:
                self.errorString = "Photo access permission not determined"
            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
    }

    fileprivate func getAllPhotos() {

        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

        let results: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: fetchOptions)
        if results.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<results.count {
                let asset = results.object(at: i)
                let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700) //You can change size here
                manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                    if let image = image {
                        self.allPhotos.append(image)
                    } else {
                        print("error asset to image")
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            self.errorString = "No photos to display"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks so much for helping me. I've tried your code to my xcode project. It to be error in me. it said like this.
"
CrashOnLaunchError: importPhotos app crashed on launch
The app crashed while updating the preview. Look for crash logs in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports for more details.
"

Comment: please share code with UIKit, I still using with UIKit @Rohit Makwana