AVPlayer Error: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'
I have a photo sorting app that currently only supports photos. In adding videos, I've encountered an error thrown by the AVPlayer used to display video files. Here's the main view, the video view, and the asset manager:
//
//  ContentView.swift
//  PhotoChoice2
//
//  Created by Garrett Post on 3/4/24.
//

import SwiftUI
import Photos

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var photos = PhotosModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                if photos.photoArray.count > 0 {
                    Text("You have no more photos!")
                    
                    if photos.photoArray.count > 1 {
                        if photos.photoArray[1].asset.mediaType == .video {
                            VideoCardView(asset: photos.photoArray[1] as! BetterVideo)
                                .environmentObject(photos)
                        } else {
                            ImageView(asset: photos.photoArray[1] as! BetterUIImage)
                                .environmentObject(photos)
                        }
                    }
                    
                    if photos.photoArray[0].asset.mediaType == .video {
                        VideoCardView(asset: photos.photoArray[0] as! BetterVideo)
                            .environmentObject(photos)
                    } else {
                        ImageView(asset: photos.photoArray[0] as! BetterUIImage)
                            .environmentObject(photos)
                    }
                    
                    ButtonsView(asset: photos.photoArray[0])
                        .environmentObject(photos)
                    
                    VStack {
                        HStack {
                            Spacer()
                            Button(
                                action: {
                                    photos.deletePhoto()
                                }, label: {
                                    Image(systemName: "trash")
                                        .resizable()
                                        .padding()
                                        .frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                            })
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                } else {
                    Text("You have no photos!")
                }
            }
            
            Spacer()
                .frame(height: 50)
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}


//
//  VideoCardView.swift
//  PhotoChoice2
//
//  Created by Garrett Post on 3/31/24.
//

import SwiftUI
import AVKit
import Photos

struct VideoCardView: View {
    let asset: BetterVideo
    var screenSize = UIScreen.main.bounds.size
    
    @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: PhotosModel
    @State private var offset = CGSize.zero
    @State private var player = AVPlayer()
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VideoPlayer(player: player)
                .frame(width: screenSize.width * 0.8, height: screenSize.height * 0.6, alignment: .center)
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25))
                .scaledToFill()
        }
        .onAppear {
            player.pause()
            player = AVPlayer()
            player = AVPlayer(playerItem: asset.video)
            player.play()
        }
        .offset(x: offset.width, y: offset.height)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(Double(offset.width / 40)))
        .gesture(
        DragGesture()
            .onChanged({ gesture in
                offset = gesture.translation
            })
            .onEnded({ _ in
                withAnimation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.15)) {
                    swipeCard(width: offset.width)
                } completion: {
                    if offset != .zero {
                        offset = .zero
                        viewModel.next()
                    }
                }
            })
        )
    }
    
    func swipeCard(width: CGFloat) {
        switch width {
        case -500...(-150):
//            delete
            offset = CGSize(width: -screenSize.width, height: 0)
            viewModel.appendToPhotosToDelete(asset.asset)
            print("User swipe left")
        case 150...(500):
//            save
            offset = CGSize(width: screenSize.width, height: 0)
            print("User swipe right")
        default:
            offset = .zero
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    VideoCardView(asset: BetterVideo(image: AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: "https://videos.pexels.com/video-files/5824198/5824198-hd_1080_1920_24fps.mp4", encodingInvalidCharacters: true)!), asset: PHAsset()))
}


//
//  PhotosModel.swift
//  PhotoChoice2
//
//  Created by Garrett Post on 3/4/24.
//
//  Originiated from https://stackoverflow.com/a/61473282/19402663.
//

import Foundation
import Photos

class PhotosModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var errorString : String = ""
    @Published var photoArray: [BetterAsset] = []
    
    private var currentIndex = 0
    private var totalInitialPhotos = 0
    
    private var photosToDelete = [PHAsset]()
    
    init() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                switch status {
                case .authorized, .limited:
                    self.errorString = ""
                    self.getInitialPhotos()
                case .denied, .restricted:
                    self.errorString = "Photo access permission denied"
                case .notDetermined:
                    self.errorString = "Photo access permission not determined"
                @unknown default:
                    fatalError()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    fileprivate func getInitialPhotos() {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let videoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        videoOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        
        let results: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
        totalInitialPhotos = results.count
        
        if results.count > 2 {
            for i in 0..<3 {
                let asset = results.object(at: i)
                let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700) //You can change size here
                if asset.mediaType == .video {
                    manager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions) { (video, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let video = video {
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterVideo(image: video, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let image = image {
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterUIImage(image: image, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            currentIndex = 3
        } else if results.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<results.count {
                let asset = results.object(at: i)
                let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700) //You can change size here
                if asset.mediaType == .video {
                    manager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions) { (video, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let video = video {
                                self.photoArray.removeLast()
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterVideo(image: video, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            if let image = image {
                                self.photoArray.removeLast()
                                self.photoArray.append(BetterUIImage(image: image, asset: asset))
                            } else {
                                print("error asset to image")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.errorString = "No photos to display"
            }
        }
        self.photoArray = self.photoArray.reversed()
        print("getAllPhotos() completed")
    }
    
    func appendToPhotosToDelete(_ asset: PHAsset) {
        photosToDelete.append(asset)
        print("appendToPhotosToDelete() completed")
    }
    
    fileprivate func getNextPhoto() {
        let manager = PHImageManager.default()
        let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestOptions.isSynchronous = false
        requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let videoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        videoOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
        let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
        fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]
        
        // TODO: Set change with .image to with fetchOptions: Gets all types
        let results: PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: fetchOptions)
        
        // TODO: Change photoArray so that it imcludes all three types
        self.photoArray = photoArray.shiftRight()
        
        let asset = results.object(at: currentIndex)
        let size = CGSize(width: 700, height: 700) //You can change size here

        // TODO: Add if statement – If video - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimagemanager/1616958-requestplayeritem, else ->
        if asset.mediaType == .video {
            manager.requestPlayerItem(forVideo: asset, options: videoOptions) { (video, _) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let video = video {
                        self.photoArray.removeLast()
                        self.photoArray.append(BetterVideo(image: video, asset: asset))
                    } else {
                        print("error asset to image")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: size, contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions) { (image, _) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if let image = image {
                        self.photoArray.removeLast()
                        self.photoArray.append(BetterUIImage(image: image, asset: asset))
                    } else {
                        print("error asset to image")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func next() {
        if currentIndex == totalInitialPhotos {
            self.photoArray = []
            return
        } else if currentIndex == totalInitialPhotos - 1 {
            self.photoArray.removeLast()
        } else if currentIndex == totalInitialPhotos - 2 {
            self.photoArray.removeLast()
        }
        
        getNextPhoto()
        
        currentIndex += 1
        print(currentIndex)
    }
    
    func deletePhoto() {
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetChangeRequest.deleteAssets(NSArray(array: self.photosToDelete))
        })
    }
}


I've looked at just initializing a new AVPlayer object, but that didn't work. The problem I can see is that the top card view doesn't get cycled. If I had to guess, it has something to do with the next item in the array being a video, but I don't have any idea how that'd be a problem. When working with photos, the app works as intended.

Change ObservedObject to StateObject. If that does not work you might try simplifying your code to the least necessary to reproduce the issue.
